# Firefox won't install on Windows 10 FCU

Tags: windows-10, firefox, installation

I'm trying to install Firefox (latest version) on a nearly clean install of Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (1709).  I download the file, and run it, and it sits stuck at 0% Extracted and stays like that forever.  Clicking cancel does nothing, I have to end task.

I've tried re-downloading, using older versions (57, 42), 32 bit and 64 bit, full installer, all the same issue.  I've also cleared my temp files.  I've previously had FF installed before I wiped the disk and re-installed.

I've also tried using the troubleshooting wizard to set Windows 8 compatibility and that didn't work either.  I've found very little googling the problem, and what I have found doesn't apply.

I'm starting to pull my hair out on this...

Comment: More information about the system will be required.  Firefox absolutely supports Windows 10 Version 1709. Your issue is a system configuration issue.

Comment: You might try using Ninite to install.  However, whatever is blocking Firefox from installing is a big problem and will cause you more problems.  Possibly antivirus.  Remember to reset temp fixes like WIndows 8 compatibility when it doesn't work , so that you're not working in a highly customized, unknown situation.

Comment: It sounds like the Windows Installer service is disabled.

Comment: @Ramhound - it's not.  The setup ran just fine once it was manually extracted.

Comment: It sounds as though he does not have permission to run exe from the system temp folders. Erik, is this a corporate-owned or domain-joined computer?

Comment: @music2myear - yes, it is domain joined.  However, I'm the administrator on this box, and have never had this problem before.

Comment: Doesn't make a real difference. If the domain security policy is such that exes cannot run from the temp directories, and an exception is not given for the admin accounts, then that is that. Extracting the installer package yourself is the work around. I do this myself on my domain joined computer, even when using my admin account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install Firefox, first download the Firefox setup installer from one of the following three websites. Use the first one if you are not accustom to surf a FTP server.

1. https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/
2. https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/
3. https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/

Choose your language and operating system and download the installer. Change the file extension by renaming **Firefox Setup.exe** to **Firefox Setup.7z** or directly open that executable installer with [7-ZIP](http://www.7-zip.org/) (free & open-source software). Double click on `core` folder, extract all those files in any directory in any partition.

[image: Firefox_extract]

It is important to extract all files and folder from that core folder otherwise Firefox may not work. After extracting, double click on `Firefox.exe` and you are ready to run Firefox.

Comment: If extracting is acceptable, one might as well use Portable Firefox.

Comment: @DanielB - hadn't thought of that.. another good option I suppose

Comment: You don't have to change the extension to .7z to extract. Using 7Zip you can just right-click on the .exe and choose to extract, and it'll work just fine.